# Floating divs, equal height - fill space with additional div without overflow

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have two div-columns of different height which I like to have the same height. I achieved this using the padding-margin hack with the following css for my div-columns:

```
.lane1 {
    padding-bottom: 800px;
    margin-bottom: -800px;
}
```

The html is displaying a flow-diagram. I would like to have a line from the end of each lane to the bottom of the two-lane part to have a continuous diagram.

[image: Example of the diagram]

I tried to achieve this with an additional div with class .LineFilling that is a line going down, but I don't know how heigh the line should be. So I put

```
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
```

in the .lane1-class and made the .LineFilling-element of height 600px, but that doesn't work, since the overflow is displayed. Is there a way to have the .LineFilling-element extend to the end of the lane? Or extend further but the overflow being cut?

Thanks for help.

EDIT: I posted the code online here: [Click here to see code](http://jsfiddle.net/RRupc/)

Comment: what are you trying to do I couldn't understand......

Comment: I want to have the line after "ACTION_SUCCESS" going done till the line with the arrow under it. The problem is that I do not know how many elements are on the right side, so I don't know how long the line has to be.

Comment: @Mr. Alien: Just posted it, please see the link at the end of the post.

Comment: In my current solution I use a background-image for the div-element. Obviously this isn't a very good solution because I need additional images, but as a work-around it is the best I could figure out till now. If anyone can offer a css-solution (or if this is not possible, a clean javascript-solution) - that would be great. I have the feeling that this should be possible with pure css. Especially with responsive design in mind, pure css would be a much better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Pure CSS solution

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/vmtCQ/) is a DEMO of that solution.

In this DEMO, you see multipple `Row`s,
each `Row` can have a variable number of columns without stating anything in the markup, and without fixing any width. (the width is always divided evenly between the columns).
Each column is called `ElementsHolder`, and can have any number of `Elements` you want.

all the column in a row will always have the same height, and the last arrow in the row will fill that space.

In the DEMO you can see 3 `Row`s.
The First `Row` has the starting point, so no stretch needed there.
The Second `Row` has 3 `ElementsHolder`, without stating anything special in the markup, 2 of them will stretch to fill the gap.
The Third `Row` has 2 `ElementsHolder`, behave as expected.

notice that the stretching works regardless of the `Element`s height. (some of them have 2 or 3 lines of text, and it works perfectly)

If you want to use that technique, you only have to implement the other kind of boxes and arrows (Curve etc..)

The solution is done by using the new CSS flex model.
the direction is set via `flex-direction: row;`, 
Each row has `ElementsHolder`s that gets equal width.

each one of those `ElementsHolder` is also a flex box, but this time his direction is opposite (`flex-direction: column;`).

the child's of `ElementsHolder` are `Element`s & `Arrow`s, I dont want them to have equal height, but to span excatly the natural height. except the last arrow, that should span the rest of the container.

all of that is achieved using the `flex` property with the appropriate values.

More about the flex-model can be found [**HERE**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: The first solution you propose is not applicable for me since the content of the div is not known. The placeholder "description" in the graph above will be replaced by text which can be of different length, therefore the divs will have different heights depending on the text.

Comment: For your second solution: I do not really get how this should solve the problem, sorry.

Comment: the second solution is harder to implement. for it to work you will need to reconstruct you layout in such a way that every box is responsible for the arrow that come out of it, and the height of those arrow are not fixed, they always stretch down to fill the whole container. now its just a matter of setting the container height with CSS table layout.

Comment: I understand that its not very clear, but it's to big for me to create that for you right now. Take a look at the demo fiddle I gave you, you can use the idea that is showed there and implement it.

Comment: @mbader Check out my updated demo (Chrome, Safari, Opera only). I will enlarge it when I'll find the time to have all your boxes and arrows type, and to make it work with other browsers (using a script).

Comment: @mbader I've implemented a **Cross-browser** CSS **only** solution. check my updated answer.

Comment: That is very close to what I need - first of all thank you. If the description is a longer text, it will still break the layout (see this http://jsfiddle.net/A9BnA/1/). Is it possible to prevent this breaking?

Comment: 2 answer. 1) in the current layout --> just make the longer container to be the static one, and make the other one stretchable. 2)If you don't care about chrome, I can remove some fix that I had to put there, and it will work fine without stating who is the static (all of them can be stretchables)

Comment: I actually just had another idea.. that should simplify things.. I'll try it later and comment if it works.

Comment: @mbader I'm proud to say it works great in all browser. (Tested in IE10, Chrome, FF) I will test on more browsers later. the markup is very simple and easy to extend. it's a perfect solution.

Comment: I really like your solution - its clean and simple. The flex-box css seems to be the answer to this problem. Unfortunately I need to support Internet Explorer at least from version 8 upward, which is why I will stick to my background-image-workaround. I'll probably install a browser switch in my css, 'cause I am very much for supporting new solutions. IE9 and smaller do not seem to support the flex-box at all, therefor I don't think that I have another choice.

Comment: @mbader I Have a solution that works with IE8+, Pure CSS. but the layout will be less flexible from the one showed here, you will have to now who is the longest column in the row, and apply a different markup for him. the rest of the row will always span to be as long as him. If you're interested, I'll make it.

Comment: It would be nice if you could add some information about the flex-box css in your answer such that other users do not need to read all the comments first.

Comment: Ok, i'll add some explanation. do you want the IE8+ (but less flexible) solution I mentioned in my past comment?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38719/discussion-between-mbader-and-avrahamcool)

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible with pure css.
I have used display table-row and table-cell properties to achieve it.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <p>line 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <p>line 1</p>
        <p>line 2</p>
        <p>line 3</p>
        <p>line 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{display:table-row;}
.child{display:table-cell;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;}
p{margin:5px 0;}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/enP9p/2/).

Update: probable solution [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7JPfH/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your proposition, how would I now add the line unter "line 1" in the left lane to the bottom of the left lane?

Comment: I need the graph that I posted in my question with the missing line unter the element ACTION_SUCCESS". How can I achieve that?

Comment: pls see updated fiddle. I have used background image for left side panel.

Comment: Thank you, but that is the solution I already had yesterday - please read my comment to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I really understand what you need. I've tried the following

Adding a new absolute element in the laneContainer with `height: 100%` ​​

```
#straightLine {
    background-color: #FFBF80;
    height: 100%;
    left: 104px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 3px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Plus some small modifications to some other objects, you'll find them in the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/RRupc/9/

Is something like that what you want?

Comment: How did you manage the straightLine-Element to appear behind the pvElem.pvBox-Element? When I tried something similar the straightLine-Element was always in front of the pvBox since the straightLine is position: absolute and the pvBox is position: relative. Can you give some explanations on this please?

Comment: sure. you can use the z-index to tell the element basically on which layer it should be. so give the pvBox z-index: 2; and the straightLine z-index: 1; That means the pvbox is on top of the line. But this is only working if you have position absolute, relative or fixed...

Update: more information here http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding another `div` to fill the space, wouldn't it be easier to add a class to the `div` on the left column, and style that to fill any spacing/line requirements you have?

So you could have:

HTML:

```
<div class="twoColumn">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="step doubleRow">
            <p>One step covering two rows here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="step">
            <p>Single size step</p>
        </div>
        <div class="step">
            <p>Single size step</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm, but how would I style the left row, not knowing how heigh the right row is (assuming that the right row is higher)?

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about that. You may be able to get away with using [one of these techniques](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) to help vertically align it.

Comment: Thank you @pea.sandwell. I carefully analysed the proposed solutions there, but none of them really help for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

have you seen these 2 plugins?

[jQuery Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)
[jQuery Mansonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Eventually there is a solution for you!?
Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

FlexBox could be worth a look too.

if you are ok with [IE10 +](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)

Auto Align Heights (CSS)

```
align-items: stretch
```

Good Reads [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/)

Cheers,

Rob